# How to add sticky section headers in listview?

Tags: android, listview, sectionheader

From Android 4.0 in the default contact app the list view has header sections.  The headers of the currently visible section remain on top of the ListView until the next new section becomes visible and pushes the old header off.

I see that there are a few gitHub projects (https://github.com/emilsjolander/StickyListHeaders) that are available to integrate this, but is there any default component or any in the Android support library component with which we can achieve this implementation?

[image: StickyListHeaders]

Comment: I would advice against it...there are android design guide lines which you should adhere to

Comment: As far as I know, Android does not support this natively.

Comment: Any idea how android 4.0 in default contact app integrated this feature?